# Importing images as a sequence in Adobe Premiere Pro using extendscript

Tags: import, extendscript, adobe-premiere

So I've been looking around and trying to find a way of importing image sequences in Adobe Premiere Pro using extendscript.

I can import separate single files using:
`app.project.importFiles(new Folder(folder_path));`

But I can't give an option of importing these images as a sequence.

I tried using  `opts = new ImportOptions(new File("path_to_image")); opts.sequence = true;` and calling this within 
`app.project.importFiles(opts)` but Premiere doesn't seem to support ImportOptions, I keep getting an error stating "*Import Options does not have a constructor*"....

I'm assuming Premiere Pro doesn't support ImportOptions?

Is there any other way of importing an image sequence using `app.project.importFiles`?

Thanks!

Comment: I've just had a look with the Data Browser in Extendscript Toolkit CC and there doesn't appear to be an ImportOptions object anywhere. app.project.importFiles() takes only one argument. So it looks like computer says no.

Comment: Argh. It's almost unbelievable that there's no way Adobe allows one to import image sequences in Premiere (using extendscript).

WHY ADOBE WHY!

Comment: And the complete lack of extendscript documentation for Premiere is baffling too - why don't they want people developing for their platform?

Comment: I have been considering a workaround where you generate an xml file and import that. Importing lots of image sequences is such a pain as it is, if you have a whole lot of them you have to do them one by one.

Comment: I tried that alternative already, dunno if I did it right but after I exported an image sequence as an XML and recreated it, I imported the recreated XML and it shows up with only the first frame of the sequence.

Comment: Dang, just tried that and you're right: it looks like it works but it just creates a still frame the length of the original clip.

Answer (score 2):

From Bruce Bullis over at Adobe (https://forums.adobe.com/message/9752499#9752499):

The last parameter to app.project.importFiles is a 0 or 1, to indicate whether or not to "interpret all the files referenced in the array-to-be-imported, as an image sequence".

See usage in PProPanel:

Samples/Premiere.jsx at master · Adobe-CEP/Samples · GitHub: https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Samples/blob/master/PProPanel/jsx/PPRO/Premiere.jsx#L201

--> 
`app.project.importFiles(importThese, 
                                                1,          // suppress warnings
                                                targetBin,
                                                0);        // import as numbered stills`